# Argon one M2 case

Tags: sd-card

I am thinking of buying the Argon one M2 case, but I am a bit concerned that you can,t get to the SD card slot. Can I put the SD Card in an adapter and use a USB port? Or would I have to put the EPROM on there to use the USB?
I looked on youtube and got the answer for myself.
I will get the Argon case.

Answer (score 1):

Putting an SD card into a USB card reader and booting from that is essentially USB mass storage boot, which is available on Raspberry Pi 2B v1.2, 3A+, 3B, 3B+, 4B, 400, Compute Module 3, Compute Module 3+ and Compute Module 4 only. Note that only Pi 3B+, 4B and Pi 400 can be set up to use an arbitrary boot order, other boards will require you to program them in USB host boot mode, which is permanent and cannot be undone, or use an SD card for boot code, while hosting the OS on USB storage.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my question after watching videos on youtube about the Argon case. This is one of them https://youtu.be/BAu-zNVDKA0?t=5
It would mean that I could not use Berryboot as you can,t have the SD in when the bottom of the case is on.

Comment: Would you care to share the link with us?